# How to print error message into text file in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

I have this simple script that will execute text.bat in cmd tool and print result in hello.txt. This is done to target remote server.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName 1.1.1.1 -Credential KOPI\Administrator -ScriptBlock {
Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\Users\Administrator.KOPI\Documents\test.bat'"

} | out-file $psscriptroot\hello.txt
```

However, the bat file encounter error as shown below.

```
ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (ERROR: The syst...y key or value.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError
    + PSComputerName        : 1.1.1.1
```

So my question is, if it is possible to print just the error message **ERROR: The system was unable to find the specified registry key or value.** into hello.txt?

Comment: `} | out-file ...` -> `} 2>&1 | out-file ...`

Comment: [About redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.1)

Comment: OP is asking for the error message only., without the whole stack :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, what you are looking for is catching an exception message (`$_.Exception.Message`).

For example:

```
try {
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName 1.1.1.1 -Credential KOPI\Administrator -ScriptBlock {
        Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\Users\Administrator.KOPI\Documents\test.bat'"
        } | out-file $psscriptroot\hello.txt
}
catch {
    $_.Exception.Message | Out-File $psscriptroot\hello.txt
}
```